# How to show a full screen Modal ContentDialog in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

When a user is trying to login to my app, I am displaying a ContentDialog containing a few TextBlocks and a ProgressBar.

I choose ContentDialog because it is modal and blocks the user until the application collects required information and is ready to navigate to next page.

The following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog) shows the Content Dialog Class that is available for Windows Phone 8.1(Universal Apps).

The following code displays the code-behind that I have written to display the ContentDialog (I have temporarily put this in OnNavigatedTo for testing, will later move it to appropriate notification function)

```
//Progress Bar
ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
bar.IsIndeterminate = true;

//Downloading Data text
TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
txt.Text = "Downloading data...";
txt.FontSize = 17;
txt.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
txt.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

//This could take a few seconds
TextBlock txt2 = new TextBlock();
txt2.Text = "This could take a few seconds.";
txt2.FontSize = 17;
txt2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
txt2.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

//Please do not close the application.
TextBlock txt3 = new TextBlock();
txt3.Text = "Please do not close the application.";
txt3.FontSize = 17;
txt3.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
txt3.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Center;

StackPanel stk = new StackPanel();
stk.Children.Add(bar);
stk.Children.Add(txt);
stk.Children.Add(txt2);
stk.Children.Add(txt3);


ContentDialog dlg = new ContentDialog();
dlg.Content = stk;
SolidColorBrush color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
color.Opacity = 0.7;
dlg.Background = color;
dlg.Margin = new Thickness(0, 250, 0, 0);
dlg.ShowAsync();
```

This is displayed as
[image]
Above you can see it is only covering part of the background

I want it to be displayed as
[image]

by making the full screen modal.

I have tried changing the height and other properties but was unable to get it to work.

I would be glad if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a solution which eliminates the code behind. Not sure if this is more of a work around. But it allows me to easily use Binding to decide when to display this modal dialog and when to hide it.

This is my XAML

```
<Grid>
<Grid Visibility="{Binding IsDownloadingData}" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Background="{StaticResource PartiallyTransparentBlackColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Downloading Data..." FontSize="17" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="This could take a few seconds." FontSize="17" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Text="Please do not close the application." FontSize="17" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
<ScrollViewer Canvas.ZIndex="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,10,0,10">
    <!-- The XAML that should be hidden goes here (In my case LOGIN PAGE XAML) -->
</ScrollViewer>
```

I play around with the visibility of the Grid that has Canvas.ZIndex="1" using Binding and decide when to display the modal window.

Comment: PLaying with *Visibility* of UIElements is also a good solution. Only remember to handle the *BackKey* of the Phone, hence it's not automatically handled.

Comment: Just a remark: dont forget to bind 'IsIndeterminate' to visibility. If Visibility will be Collapsed, but IsIndeterminate will be still true, it'd still run in a background.

Answer (score 12):

You can for example put a Grid as a content of your `ContentDialog` and set its *Height/Width* as *Bounds* of Current Window or your LayoutGrid:

```
// your code
stk.VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Center;
Grid contentGrid = new Grid();
contentGrid.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
contentGrid.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
// or from LayoutGrid
//contentGrid.Height = LayoutRoot.ActualHeight;
//contentGrid.Width = LayoutRoot.ActualWidth;
contentGrid.Width -= 40; // it seems that ContentDialog has some defaul margin
contentGrid.Children.Add(stk);

ContentDialog dlg = new ContentDialog();
dlg.Content = contentGrid;
SolidColorBrush color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
color.Opacity = 0.7;
dlg.Background = color;
await dlg.ShowAsync();
```

You can also think of using a [PopUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup).

Comment: Popup is not an option because it is not Modal.

Comment: The solution that you have given above works perfectly. Thanks. But I am using MVVM Pattern and it encourages almost no code-behind. Can you think of any way to move this out of the code behind? I have one anser below using Canvas.ZIndex and playing with the visibility. But I am not sure if it is more of a work around and not the right way.

Comment: The mvvm pattern is not a "no code behind" pattern. It's a pattern in which your app logic should not be aware of your interface. That's completely different.
Yes you should avoid code behind, to make your xaml the most maintainable possible, but if code behind can solve your problem, don't hesitate

Answer (score 5):

In Windows Phone 8.1, ContentDialog has `FullSizeDesired` boolean property which, when set to true, will open the dialog in full size mode. ([MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.fullsizedesired.aspx)).You'd need to set `Background` to a transparent color value if desired.