# Windows phone 8.1 launch login ContentDialog on App Start before Mainpage

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1, messagedialog

Please I am new to windows phone and any other platform development. I want to add a login screen to my app using ContentDialog. I have no clue and have found nothing by way of example on how to make it show before the mainpage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show a full screen Modal ContentDialog in Windows Phone 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372271/how-to-show-a-full-screen-modal-contentdialog-in-windows-phone-8-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kennyzx thank you for pointing the link to me. here is hoe I solved my problem by placing the code below  in my 'App.xaml.cs'

```
protected async override void OnWindowCreated(WindowCreatedEventArgs e)
    {            
        //Lunch ContentDialog
        LoginPage signInDialog = new LoginPage();
        await signInDialog.ShowAsync();

        if (signInDialog.Result == SignInResult.SignInOK)
        {
            // Sign in was successful.

        }
        else if (signInDialog.Result == SignInResult.SignInFail)
        {
            // Sign in failed.
            // Exit the app after three attempts                
            Application.Current.Exit();
        }
        else if (signInDialog.Result == SignInResult.SignInCancel)
        {
            // Sign in was cancelled by the user.
            // Exit the app
            Application.Current.Exit();
        }
    }
```