# How to show an alert in Windows Universal Apps with Radio buttons which does not light dismiss?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am working on Universal apps and I am new in this platform. I want to display an Alert box with languages in it and get input from User based on RadioButton checked. I used CustomMessageBox in Windows Phone 8 for this purpose. But its not available in Windows Universal apps. So, I tried MessageDialog but in that we can't add other controls. After some research I found a Control named Flyout, using which I  was able to display Radio button and got user input. But if user taps outside that flyout then the flyout closes. So the language is not selected. Please can anyone suggest a control which can be used.

Comment: You might be interested in this question's answers:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/24372271/996081

Comment: Thanks but ContentDialog control is not available in Windows 8.1

Comment: I don't think the accepted answer uses ContentDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [User Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227647). You can style it as you need and make it look like an alert box and place all your radio-buttons and stuffs inside.

User controls does not contain the IsLightDismiss property (*Light dismiss is when the user taps on any area other than the popup.*) as pop-ups have, so the user control will not get dismissed until a condition is met.

User controls has Visibility property, by using this you can show/hide it according to your conditions and logic.

Comment: Thanks @Utsav. If possible can you explain with a sample code?

Comment: You can check this link to get an idea of user control. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/828355/Making-a-quick-rating-user-control-for-Windows-Pho

Comment: Thanks @Utsav I created one UserControl based on my requirement but after I got the input from user , I was not ab;e to set visibility property to collapsed. Can you help me with that.?

Comment: are you using mvvm pattern?

Comment: No, got it. I did a small mistake due to which it was not visible. Is it possible to use the UserControl in c# code on any other page?

Comment: Yes its very much possible. That is the main reason why we use user controls. Re-usability! If my answer helped you don't forget to give a vote up and approval.